# python erroneously skipping last line of last file in a list

Tags: python

I have written a program in Python v3.3 that opens a list of files in turn and performs an operation using the data from each file. For some reason, however, the program consistently  ignores the last line of the last file in the list when opening files. All the previous files are read normally. The files themselves have identical formatting and there are not additional white space or newline characters in the last file in the list that are not present in all the other files.

The code is below:

```
counter3=0
for counter3 in range(counter3,numSteps):
# open up each step in the list of steps across the chromosomal segment:
    L=shlex.shlex(stepFileIndex[counter3],posix=True)
    L.whitespace += '\t'
    L.whitespace_split = True
    L=list(L)
    #print(L)
    stepNumber = int(L[0])
    stepStart = int(L[1])
    stepStop = int(L[2])
    stepSize = int(stepStop-(stepStart-1))
#Now open the file of SNPs corresponding with the window in question and convert it into a list:
    currentStepFile = open(("C:/Users/gwilymh/Desktop/Python/Sliding Window Analyses-2/%s_%s_step_%s.txt")%(str(segmentNumber),str(segmentName),str(counter3+1)),'r')
    currentStepFile = list(currentStepFile)
    nSNPsInCurrentStepFile = len(currentStepFile)
    print("number of SNPs in this step is:", nSNPsInCurrentStepFile)
    print(currentStepFile)
```

The last two files in the list are below:

```
1_segment1_step_7.txt
['1503', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C']
['1505', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'G']

1_segment1_step_8.txt
['1950', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G']
['1967', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'G']
```

Comment: where is numSteps defiend?

Comment: shouldn't there be a `currentStepFile.readlines()` in there? I only see a list on a filehandle...

Comment: No, technically that will work.

Comment: @Fredrik no, `list(filehandle)` causes an implicit iteration/read of the full file the same way as doing a `for` over it.

Comment: So it does, I had to try. Don't like it even if I learnt something new :-)

Comment: @Fredrik: In fact, you should almost never call `readlines()`. The only reason it's still in the language is because `readlines(sizehint)` _is_ often useful.

Comment: I generated an file indexing the number of steps. Each step is on a newline in this index file. The index file is opened under the filehandle 'stepFileIndex', and converted into a list (stepFileIndex=list(stepFileIndex). The number of steps is generated via the command: numSteps = len(stepFileIndex).

Comment: @gwilymh: It would be much easier to answer your question if you didn't use one-letter variable names like `L` and meaningless longer names like `counter3`, reuse the same variables for different purposes, etc.

Comment: @gwilymh: While we're at it: You don't need `str(x)` to pass it to a `%s`; that implicitly calls `str`. You also have some extra parens you don't need. And lines way longer than 80 chars. All of this also contributes to making your code harder to read and debug.

Comment: @gwilymh: More importantly, can you give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that we can run, with same input and expected and actual output, so we know exactly what we're dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

Are the files being written while the script is running?

Apart from dangling file handles and maybe a buffer that should have been emptied either via `f.close()` or `f.flush()` I don't see anything wrong in the code.

You could however improve your code by not using `list(filehandle)` and instead replacing it with a `for` loop. As you probably noticed by the comments, it's not a common way of doing it.

Also because you replace the variable that points to the filehandle `currentStepFile`, your code will have to wait for garbage collection to close it.

If you also do this elsewhere in your code, it's likely to be the cause of this or other problems in the future.

Comment: Hi Unode. To clarify, what do you mean by 'dangling file handles'? and do you suspect that the problem is stems from using a list instead of a loop, or because I am not closing the filehandles, or both?

Comment: @gwilymh A dangling file handle is the result of opening a file with `f = open(filename)` and not closing it with `f.close()`. Since Python buffers writing to files to avoid hitting the disk at every `f.write()` action, it may so happen that the file is incomplete when your other part of the code tries to read it.

Comment: Thank you Unode. Closing all the open filehandles seems to have fixed the problem.